# I keep getting 400 Bad Request from my Axios Post Request (React/Redux Toolkit/Typescript)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I keep getting 400 Bad Request error for my Axios post request from my createAsyncThunk. Can anyone lend me a second pair of eyes?? The request is an attempt to add a reading list to the user's database entry.

Here is my react onClick function which contains the dispatch:

```
const createList = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     
     const listData: listObject=
        {listID: uuidv4(),
         listTitle: (e.target as any)[0].value,
        listComment: "",
        listMakerID: userID,
         listMadeTime: Date(),
        listFolder: [],
        list: []}

     dispatch(createNewList(listData))
 }
```

Here is my createAsyncThunk 'createNewList' which I exported to the above onCLick function:

```
export const createNewList = createAsyncThunk("myLists/createNewList", async (listData) => {
    try{
    const response = axios.post("http://localhost:3020/createList", {data: listData})
    return await response
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

and here is my backend router:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.send({hi: 'there'})
  })
  app.post('/signup', Authentication.signup
  )
  app.post('/signin', requireSignin, Authentication.signin)
  app.post('/addToList', requireSignin, crud.addToList)
  app.post('/createList', requireSignin, crud.createList)
  }
```

and here is my "crud" file which include the createList server function

```
exports.createList=function(req, res, next){
    
    
    const data=req.body.data
    const userID = data.listMakerID
    User.updateOne({uniqueID: userID}, { $push: { lists: data } })
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization");  

    res.send("successful")
    
  }
```

Since 400 is a client-side error, am I missing something here? Maybe I need to send nested objects in a special way? The content-type in my request header is "application/json" on postman, also only getting 400 bad request errors.

Comment: 400 is a server-side error. You might have sent the wrong request, but your server gives the error. You might add some more error handling on the server and see if that logs something interesting.